# Unable to find liquidsoap_binary in your path

Tags: windows, ubuntu-server, windows-server-2016, icecast, liquidsoap

all.
This is a Windows 2016 server installation.
I am in the process of trying to do what I need on a windows system, however. If it proves that I cannot do what I need, then at which time, I will move over to a Linux system and use it to run IceCast and LiquidSoap. But I will not give up easily. And with that said.

I have been following the instructions on installing Liquidsoap from the following site.
https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/creating-internet-radio-station-icecast-and-liquidsoap
When I run this part here, it succeeds

```
git clone https://github.com/savonet/liquidsoap-daemon
```

Then, I run this line

```
cd liquidsoap-daemon
```

Next, I run this line.

```
./daemonize-liquidsoap.sh
```

With this, I get the following error.

```
which: no liquidsoap in (/home/darkmedia/.opam/4.06.1+mingw64c/
bin:/usr/local/
bin:/usr/
bin:/cygdrive/
c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/
c/Windows:/cygdrive/
c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/
c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/
c/Users/darkmedia/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps)
Unable to find liquidsoap_binary in your path.
```

I read that I will need to build the binary, but, with no knowledge of how to do this, I am stuck. Could someone please assist with helping me to get liquidsoap installed?
Thank you.

Update-------
I installed Ubuntu 18.04 Server, and have run into the same issue as above, with

```
Unable to find liquidsoap_binary in your path.
```

Comment: Liquidsoap is nothing short of a nightmare to get installed, especially if you're building it from source.  I've had much better success with getting it running on Linux.  Ubuntu has most of the packages you need.

Comment: Oh, the fun of learning new things. So, I downloaded and installed through VirtualBox, the Ubuntu Server. And am having a fit trying to get it working properly. Not a huge fan of this text interface. I have tried to install the desktop to the server, to make it a little easier for me. However, am running into networking issues. Would be nice if there was a complete write up of everything a newb would need to get this joker up and running.

Comment: Hum, forgot to configure the networking for the virtualbox. Working on installing the desktop now. Will update this thread once I get everything installed. And working with LiquidSoap

Comment: For what it's worth, I have a script that was used to install Liquidsoap.  I used to charge $1,200 for it and people would pay it.  That's how much of a hassle this can be.  :-)  I'd post it as an answer for you but I doubt it's still up-to-date.  I haven't ran it in quite awhile.

Comment: An update. Following the information in the link, I provided in the Thread. I am getting the same error when I get to this point of ......  ./daemonize-liquidsoap.sh ---- unable to find liquidsoap_binary in your path... So, it bricks on Windows and now on Ubuntu Server at the same point in time. As for the script, sure, post it, and I will check it out.

Comment: @Brad I am downloading ubuntu-16.04.4 to test install it if I can get Liquidsoap running on it, then I will do the upgrade to 18.04. I have also found some liquidsoap installs scripts as well. So, when you post yours, if it will run with 16.04.4, that will be great. Just need to know how to run it.

Comment: Followed the information on this link here. and was able to get it working. At least, so far anyway. Will post more later. [link](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2018/01/27/how-to-install-liquidsoap-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-gnulinux/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is what I did.
I was able to get this installed.
I used the [Ubuntu Software Center]
And using this command

```
apt:liquidsoap
```

(From the following link [liquidsoap-on-ubuntu](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2018/01/27/how-to-install-liquidsoap-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-gnulinux/) )

everything installed and I am now setting up liquidsoap on Ubuntu 18.04